# When do values get written to a Google Sheet cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm experiencing a weird issue.  When I type text in a Google Sheet cell, then run a custom script (below) to get those values, it doesn't get the values I just type in.  The values only become available once I move away from that cell (`tab` or `enter`).

`var data = dataRange.getValues();`

I'm not sure when the values actually get written to the cell.  If I script a move away from that cell (below), I get the same issue.

`var newRange = sheet.getRange("C4");
sheet.setCurrentCell(newRange);`

Is there a way to write all the data to the sheet?

Can test using this code.  Write some text to A1, run custom script and check the logs.  If you don't move away from A1 before running script, logs will be empty.

```
function moveTest(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var newRange = sheet.getRange("A2");
  sheet.setCurrentCell(newRange);
  var cellOfInterest = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  Logger.log(cellOfInterest);
}
```

Edit: same issue with `setActiveSelection` instead of `setCurrentCell`

Comment: From my experience they're written as soon as the cell looses focus.  So when I run the function `function runOne(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell().getValue());
}` I see the value in the toast immediately because the cell has lost focus when I run the function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Google Spreadsheet using script, how to force flush a user's input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344067/in-google-spreadsheet-using-script-how-to-force-flush-a-users-input)

Comment: I ended up just removing the 'button' on the sheet and placing the script call in a custom menu.  It's a round about way of solving the issue.  I still think Google should implement a way for a script to force write the data to the sheet.  I've tried a bunch of solutions, but most have pretty obvious corner cases which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2):

> When do values get written to a Google Sheet cell?

When you press tab, arrow keys, enter or any other method that takes the focus away from the cell, the value gets written or committed.

Comment: Is there a script to write the values?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. But  you did try `range.setValues()` right?

Comment: My question is actually a duplicate of this previous question from 6 years ago that described the problem better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344067/in-google-spreadsheet-using-script-how-to-force-flush-a-users-input

Comment: @Craig Agree with the answers there. Not possible or unreliable at best.

Comment: Using the arrow keys also writes the value too, I think you should add this for completion sake

Comment: @Rafa Done`````````````````​`````````````````

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it would work for you, but if you are checking for 1 exact cell, an if statement checking if the input is recognized before running the script would be alright:

```
    function checkwritten(){
      var app = SpreadsheetApp;
      var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
      var InterestCell = sheet.getRange("A1");
      var cellOfInterest = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

      if (InterestCell.isBlank()) {
        Logger.log("missing value");
        ui.alert('There are missing values');
      }
      else {
        Logger.log(cellOfInterest);
        /*
        enter code here
        */
      }
    }
```

The other solutions proposed, such as making the button a menu option, or greying out the button until all entry is filled is also viable.

If you are checking for a range, the following two options are viable:

Option 1: create a cell with countblank in your sheet and it would be the cell of interest.

```
function checkwritten(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var InterestCell = sheet.getRange("A6");
  var cellOfInterest = sheet.getRange("A6").getValue();

  if (cellOfInterest == 0) {
    Logger.log("success");
  }
  else {
    Logger.log(cellOfInterest);
    /*
    enter code here
    */

  }

}
```

Option 2 - allow the script to ensure that there is no blank cells before running.

```
function checkwritten(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var CellCheckCount = 100; // 1 above the total number of rows to check
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var BlankCellCount = 0;
  var CheckCell = null;

  for (var i = 1; i < CellCheckCount; i++){
    CheckCell = sheet.getRange(i,1); //currently set to check column 1 up till 100-1 row
    if (CheckCell.isBlank()){
        BlankCellCount++;
        }
    else{
        }
  }

  if (BlankCellCount == 0) {
    Logger.log("success");
    /*
    enter code here
    */
  }
  else {
    Logger.log("fail" + BlankCellCount);
  }
}
```

Comment: In my case, it could be 1 cell or 100 cells.  So I'm not able to tell if the user has completed their entries.  Thanks for the input though, I suspect your solution would work if the script is looking for input in a single cell.

Comment: Hi Craig.Pearce one option would be to create a cell with the formula =isblank(range to check). and change the script from if (InterestCell.isBlank()) { to if (cellOfInterest = 0) { 

I have added the two possible solutions to my answer.

Comment: Hi Edmund - thanks for updating.  I tried your solution and it works majority of the time, except when the last row is the blank row (or row with data that hasn't been submitted yet).  I've solved my particular issue by simply putting the script call in a custom menu (when the user clicks the menu, all data is submitted).  I'll continue to poke around with your solution and see if I can find an answer.

Comment: is the number you enter in CellCheckCount 1 more than the number of rows you would like to check? Because the formula checks for i<CellCheckCount, if you would want to check for 100 rows, you need to enter 101 so that i would repeat up till 100

Comment: Yes I realize that, but if your script detects how many rows you have, and the bottom row has the data yet to be written, then it won't check that row.  It will tell the script there are 4 rows, and it will check 4 rows (missing the 5th row with the unwritten data).

Comment: Hi Craig, but the script does not choose the number of rows to check based on how many rows have been inputted, unless you changed the formula from a hard-coded number to a getLastRow(). I have tried running the script with the last row blank and it worked.

Comment: Sorry I guess this didn't come across properly "In my case, it could be 1 cell or 100 cells."  What I meant was, it can be any number of rows, therefore the script needs to find the range using the getLastRow method, which won't return the correct amount if the last row hasn't been written.