# How to avoid google sheet script not recording newly input value if cells stays highlighted?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've noticed that a google sheet script doesn't execute properly if an inexperienced user leaves an input cell highlighted after inputting a new value.

That could be manually solved by clicking the ENTER key on the keyboard, or some other key, then running the script; so I thought a way around was to mimic a keyboard input, but I'm unsure if there's any better solution.

As an example, I'd like the script to execute the "ENTER" key, before and after it executes the test multiplying function, as in the following test sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TMjakai_5b_UHhXHSu3TWJeI7saAeQd64H6WYWDNHfE/edit?usp=sharing

The script I'm using for a test is the following:

```
    function Test() { 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); 
    var y = formS.getRange("A3").getValue();
    var z = formS.getRange("B3").getValue();
    var x = y * z;
    formS.getRange("E3").setValue(x);
  }
```

Anyone can try it on google sheet: just click (once or twice) on either cell A3 or B3, leaving them highlighted, and click the button to execute the script.
Without clicking outside the cell or using ENTER by keyboard, the script won't record the newly inputted value.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't reproduce your issue (see gif attached).

There might be two potential issues.

Either you need to [flush](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()) the changes:

```
function Test() { 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); 
    var y = formS.getRange("A3").getValue();
    var z = formS.getRange("B3").getValue();
    var x = y * z;
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    formS.getRange("E3").setValue(x);
}
```

or you misunderstood the output of the script.

Namely, after you click on the button once, `5*44` gives `220`. Therefore, if you press it again the result (`220`) simply **won't** change because the result of  `5*44` will always be the same.

**Illustration based on your code:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried flushing but it doesn't solve it.

Somehow, the google sheet script doesn't recognize the newly input value(s) if the input cell is kept highlighted as in the image:
https://imgur.com/a/gECG5QC

Therefore you are forced to either click outside the input cell or clicking "ENTER" on keyboard. So I was trying to fit inside the function script a forced enter key to be registered without a better way to handle it; but I'm unsure if that's possible and how to do it.

Comment: @Honze Unfortunately I can't reproduce your issue. If there is a bug I would advice you to report it to the issue tracker : https://issuetracker.google.com

Comment: @Marco Ok; do you happen to know a way for a script to execute an "enter" keyboard input, by any chance?
I'd try that as a last resort.

Comment: @Honze no that is not available

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help.
I'll have to figure some way to eventually refocus a user's input; at this point I guess it can only be done manually.

Comment: @Marios on the picture both values are already in the cells. An issue happens, when one star entering new value, and press "Multiply" before pressing Enter or Clickin a mouse to finalize an input...
Flush in a script not solving.

Answer (score 0):

A cell value won't get updated until you press enter or click another cell (see [Edit & format a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/46973?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)):

> #### Edit data in a cell:
>
> 1. Open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
> 2. Click a cell that’s empty, or double-click a cell that isn’t empty.
> 3. Start typing.
> 4. Optional: To add another line within a cell, press ⌘ + Enter on a Mac or Ctrl + Enter on Windows.
> 5. When you’re done, press **Enter**.

An attached button cannot be used to force this cell update, so a script called via [clickable image/drawing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets) won't have this information.

Therefore, I'd suggest not firing your function via an attached button, but using one of the following:

- Call this via an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger (it won't get called until the user presses enter or clicks another cell, updating the cell).
- Call this via a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_slides_or_forms) (the cell will be updated when the menu item is clicked).

This way, you would make sure that the executed function works with the updated value.

#### Related:

- [How to force flush a user's input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60139262)