# Google Script > How to exit a cell programmatically?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my first Google Script. The interface is in French.
Users fill cells in a sheet named "Add song". By clicking the "Enregistrer" button (=*record*), the data is copied to another sheet ("SongList").

[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SShuD.png)

It's a natural behavior to click the button without exiting the last filled cell. So it remains in **edit mode**. And of course the value of the cell is not copied to the SongList sheet.
Only 3 fields are mandatory. So there's no control for the other 3.

Any idea on how to force the interface to leave the cell? Of course I tried getRange and setActiveCell methods, but they don't work (by the way, very surprised to see that a cell can be selected while another is in edit mode).

Here's the code:

```
function addData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var addSong = ss.getSheetByName('Add song');
  var songList = ss.getSheetByName('SongList');
  var band = addSong.getRange('D4').getValue();
  var song = addSong.getRange('H4').getValue();
  var user = addSong.getRange('D15').getValue();

  // DATA CONTROL
  if(band.length==0) {
    addSong.getRange('D4').activate();
    Browser.msgBox('Merci de renseigner le nom du groupe !', Browser.Buttons.OK);
    return;
  }

  if(song.length==0) {
    addSong.getRange('H4').activate();
    Browser.msgBox('Merci de renseigner le titre de la chanson !', Browser.Buttons.OK);
    return;
  }

  if(user.length==0) {
    addSong.getRange('D15').activate();
    Browser.msgBox('Merci de renseigner le nom du membre !', Browser.Buttons.OK);
    return;
  }

  // DATA RECORD
  var lastRow = songList.getLastRow()+1;

  songList.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy"));
  songList.getRange(lastRow, 2).setValue(band);
  songList.getRange(lastRow, 3).setValue(song);
  songList.getRange(lastRow, 4).setValue(user);
  songList.getRange(lastRow, 18).setValue(addSong.getRange('D9').getValue());  // Tuning
  songList.getRange(lastRow, 19).setValue(addSong.getRange('H9').getValue());  // Song duration
  songList.getRange(lastRow, 20).setValue(addSong.getRange('D11').getValue()); // Tempo

  Browser.msgBox('Données enregistrées !', Browser.Buttons.OK);

  // RESET FORM
  addSong.getRange('D4:D11').clearContent();
  addSong.getRange('H4:H9').clearContent();
  addSong.getRange('D4').activate();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Another guy had the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344067/how-to-force-flush-a-users-input
Maybe he managed to be clearer than me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

### solution 1 : replace the button with a custom menu

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(' Menu ')
    .addItem(' valider ici', 'addData')
    .addToUi();
}
```

### solution 2 : include the form (html) in sidebar

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
It doesn't work but lead me to a similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344067/how-to-force-flush-a-users-input
It seems there's no way to get this done until Google implements keystroke events.

Comment: ok, the solution is to replace the button by a custom menu